# why google analytics has not script type attribute

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Why google ignores `type` attribute in its script. Should I add the `type="text/javascript"` myself? What is the programmatic reason behind this?

Sample analytics code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'sample code', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Probably, HTML5. Of course, it isn't mandatory. The script will run anyway no matter the HTML version.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because all the browsers out there will default to 'text/javascript' if you do not specify a type. It's wasted characters and you shouldn't use it anymore. From [MDN HTML Element Script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> Omitted or a JavaScript MIME type: For HTML5-compliant browsers this indicates the script is JavaScript. HTML5 spec urges authors to omit the attribute rather than provided a redundant MIME type. In earlier browsers, this identified the scripting language of the embedded or imported (via the src attribute) code. JavaScript MIME types are listed in the specification.